# Динамичное обновление текста в 2 разных Label. javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Пишу клиент-серверноое приложение (чат). Клиент отправляет сообщение -> сервер его  принимает и отправляет все остальным клиентам.  Сначало сделал просто обновление Label'a с сообщениями (через Task) и все нормально работало. Теперь же надо ещё 1 Label для отображание списка подключенных клиеинтов, сервер отправляет строку с информациею через такую форму: `"/тип/сообщение"` например `"/m/hello!"` это сообщение hello. `"/n/User"` означает что подключился новый пользователь с ником User.  Как сделать что бы при получаении строки от сервера клиент обновлял конкретный Label в зависимости от типа сообщения?

Comment: знаете, что такое MVC? вот его вам и надо реализовать. у вас должна меняться модель и отображение (view) должно использовать данные из модели.

Comment: я что такое mvc, проблема в другом, обновлять label получается только в методе где создавалась сцена, но ещё проблема в дургом: пока сервер не отправит строку label так и будет ждать этой строки и в итоге зависнит. все бы легко решалось если бы прием строки от сервера и обновление label был в отдельном потоке, но javafx не позволяет этого сделать

Comment: MVC - это паттерн. да, обновления UI возможны только из UI потока, но это легко решается - `Platform.runLater`

Comment: ну скорее всего это верное решение (т.к. везде это пишут), но я не могу найти рабочий вариант реализации, т.к. код который я нахожу в гугле не работает. Можешь набросать примерный код?

Comment: верное. я немного разбираюсь в этом. вот вам [вариант](https://github.com/Vaysman/SimpleMVC) для swing, но доработать для javafx не сложно.